# reloadData gets called twice?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, reloaddata

I have been looking at this code for my app for a long time. When a user adds a ALBUM, it adds it to a array (listOfItems) in the RootViewController. The different class then calls it to update (reloadData). After looking though some NSLogs, it does the following

- `numberOfRowsInSection` updates how many rows (correct)
- `cellForRowAtIndexPath` displays rows (NSLog shows that the listOfItems is correct)
- `numberOfRowsInSection` repeats and deletes all new data
- `cellForRowAtIndexPath` repeats yet again, and it shows everything but the new data

I have no idea why it repeats - I am only calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` once.

And I have checked all my NSTimers, I even let the app just sit there for about a minute to nothing in console shows up.

Please help!
Coulton

*PS: If you need any code, please ask!*

---

**Edit:** Here's a sample NSLog of what's going on

```
Number Of Rows: 3
Array: (One, Two, Three)
```

Cell Text: One
    Cell Text: Two
    Cell Text: Three

--- Add cell of "Four" ---

```
Number of Rows: 4
Array: (One, Two, Three, Four)

Number of Rows: 3
Array: (One, Two, Three)

Cell Text: One
Cell Text: Two
Cell Text: Three
```

---

Edit: Full RootViewContoller.m

```
REMOVED
```

PS: Sorry for the long code but thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but try to outcomment `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in `viewWillAppear` if you have that in your class. It seems to be a bug in newer versions of the sdk.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The CellForRowAtIndexPath repeats for each cell shown in your tableview, more info required regarding where you are placing your NSLogs.

Comment: I am not seeing the areas you are putting your NSLog codes, (maybe a sample code illustrating how you got those nslogs). I don't see how those are causing problems tho.

Comment: Just added my RootViewController.m

Answer (score 2):

Add a breakpoint somewhere in the implementation of `numberOfRowsInSection`. When you hit the breakpoint switch to the debugger view and look at the stack trace. Do this for both calls that you get.
Look down in the stack until you find methods that belong to you (the appear bolded). You should be able to figure out where you are calling `reloadData`.

If for a breakpoint hit, you can't find any methods of your own as the source of the call, then maybe you do have a NSTimer or something that calls it for you.

Happy debugging :)

Comment: Added breakpoints but the app won't load. This is no good because I add the content later.

Comment: You can add breakpoints even after the application started. Just start the application and get a point where you think you are close to loading the data you mention. Then go to XCode, add the breakpoint and continue using the application until you hit the breakpoint. This way you won't get stuck on every screen on every reloadData.  A more cool way to do this would be to use conditional breakpoints. I've never used them so far so I can't help you with these, but I know they exist: breakpoints that trigger only when a condition is satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else has this problem, simply use a NSTimer to reload the data every X seconds. I even did a little counter on the ARAAY that populates the data and the ROWS currently in the table to see if it is necessary to update. If not, it doesn't do anything.